# Standard input swift

Tags: swift, input

i have some problems with completing one of the tasks because of input:
When i want to input two files with " " i use this code and it works perfectly:

```
let array = readLine()?.split(separator: Character(" ")).map(String.init).map(Int.init)
```

When new task asked me to read two files with \n (shift+enter, new line) i tried this code:

(like this):

## 1

## 10

```
let array = readLine()?.split(separator: Character("\n")).map(String.init).map(Int.init)
```

but it doesn't work. I'm sure that problem in this but i can't understand what I'm doing wrong and how should i rewrite this

Comment: `readLine()` reads a single line from standard input. To read two lines, call `readLine()` twice.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you very much! It was the answer i was looking for